# Typescript - Type array with at least one of each object

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have 3 types of object like this

```
type mainType = {type:'main', name?:string}
type contentType = {type:'content', text?:string}
type buttonType = {type:'button', name:string}
```

and i would like to type an array that have **at least one** of each type.
Let's say it would like like this

```
[
{type:'main'},
{type:'main', name:'Some name'},
{type:'content', text:"Some text"},
{type:'button', name:'Add'},
{type:'button', name:'Submit'}
]
```

Whats the solution to type it?

Union types not working, since it won't check if one of that type is missing.

Closest solution is using spread operator? , but it won't work if i dont know what would be the order.

Thats my first question here, hope it makes sense.

Comment: There is no specific type that works this way.  You could use a generic type and a generic helper function, but could you provide a [mre] demonstrating how you'd intend to use this?  Are you concerned about code that *supplies* an array of this type?  Or are you worried about *consuming* an array of this type?  Or both?  Examples showing your use cases would help a lot.

Comment: (continued) for example, [this thing](https://tsplay.dev/mxxaGm) shows how one might write a helper type and function to check an array, but it's a lot of type juggling so it might or might not be appropriate depending on the use case.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz ! I thought there is some easy way to do this that i don't know about but this is exacly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is at or past the edge of what I'd consider reasonably expressible in TypeScript.

---

First, there is no specific type `type GoodArray = ⋯` in TypeScript that represents what you're talking about.

TypeScript has [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) which can represent arrays with elements of specific types at specific numeric indexes.  But you don't care which indices hold the elements of your types as long as they all appear at least once.  That means your requirement would need to be written as an infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the tuple types that work the way you want... something like

```
type M = MainType; type C = ContentType; type B = ButtonType; 
type SomeType = M | C | B; type S = SomeType;

type GoodArray =
  [M, C, B] | [M, B, C] | [C, M, B] | [C, B, M] | [B, M, C] | [B, C, M] |
  [M, C, B, S] | [M, C, S, B] | [M, B, C, S] | [M, B, S, C] | [M, S, C, B] | [M, S, B, C] |
  [C, M, B, S] | [C, M, S, B] | [C, B, M, S] | [C, B, S, M] | [C, S, M, B] | [C, S, B, M] |
  [B, C, M, S] | [B, C, S, M] | [B, M, C, S] | [B, M, S, C] | [B, S, C, M] | [B, S, M, C] |
  [S, C, B, M] | [S, C, M, B] | [S, B, C, M] | [S, B, M, C] | [S, M, C, B] | [S, M, B, C] |
  [M, C, B, S, S] | [M, C, S, B, S] | [M, C, S, S, B] | [M, B, C, S, S] |
  ⋯
```

TypeScript doesn't support infinite unions.  You could choose some relatively small maximum array length to support and that could work, in that you'd just have a huge union instead of an infinite one.  This isn't really feasible either.

---

You could make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type instead of a specific one, that acts like a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the type, so that `T extends GoodArray<T>` if and only if `T` is valid.

And then you'd also have to make a generic helper function `goodArray()` that would accept an argument and validate its type.  So that instead of writing `const arr: GoodArray<⋯> = [⋯];` and manually write out the `T` type argument, you can write `const arr = goodArray([⋯]);`

Unfortunately it's not really straightforward to do this either.  The generic type needs to figure out which, if any, element types are missing, and then require those somewhere.  One way to do this is to make a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to parse the input.  Like this maybe:

```
type Remainder<T, U> = T extends unknown ? [U] extends [T] ? never : T : never

type GoodArray<T extends any[], U, A extends any[] = []> =
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? GoodArray<R, Remainder<U, F>, [...A, F]> :
  [U] extends [never] ? A : A extends [...infer I, infer L] ? [...I, U, L] : [U, ...U[]];
```

I don't know if it's worth walking through that; the point is to walk through `T`, keeping track of which types have been used, and then at the end either return the array unchanged or to modify the last element or two to require the missing types.  So we'd see:

```
type GoodExample = GoodArray<[M, C, B], S>
// type GoodExample = [MainType, ContentType, ButtonType] 
type BadExample = GoodArray<[M, B, B], S>
// type BadExample = [MainType, ButtonType, ContentType, ButtonType]
```

Then the helper function; ideally we'd write `<T extends GoodArray<T>>(arr: T) => arr`, but that's an illegally circular constraint. So we need to play games with inference and variadic tuples and... well, this:

```
const goodArray = <T extends SomeType[]>(arr:
  [...T extends GoodArray<T, SomeType> ? T : GoodArray<T, SomeType>]
) => arr;
```

We can test it, and it works:

```
const ok = goodArray([
  { type: 'main' },
  { type: 'main', name: 'Some name' },
  { type: 'content', text: "Some text" },
  { type: 'button', name: 'Add' },
  { type: 'button', name: 'Submit' }
]); // okay

const bad = goodArray([
  { type: 'main' },
  { type: 'main', name: 'Some name' },
  // { type: 'content', text: "Some text" },
  { type: 'button', name: 'Add' },
  { type: 'button', name: 'Submit' } // error!
  //~~~~ <-- Type '"button"' is not assignable to type '"content"'.
])

const alsoBad = goodArray([]); // error!
//  --------------------> ~~
//  Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 1.
```

But it's complicated.

---

And finally, all of this will only allow you to validate some specific array literal written out by a developer.  The compiler doesn't "understand" the constraint.  If you have a function that accepts a `GoodArray` or a `GoodArray<T>` it won't really "know" that, for example, a `ButtonType` is definitely present:

```
function wontKnow<T extends SomeType[]>(arr: T) {
  const x = arr.find((x): x is ButtonType => x.type === "button").name; // error!
  //  --->  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Object is possibly 'undefined'.
}
```

The [`find()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns a possibly `undefined` value no matter what.  So you'll find yourself either needing to make extra runtime checks or [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to avoid such errors.

---

Anyway, all of this means: I wouldn't really try to rely on the type system for this sort of thing, or at least I would be very aware of the limitations involved.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgSwHYBVzQLxQN5VJALigHIBbRJYgGiiTlIgH4iBnYAJ2QHMoBfAKHzQAwgHskwCBLSQoWXEKLEAxuMkTqeCAA9gzKG05IeAoVABCAV2DBxMzDjzolAI2u3KNOg1YdufQXQoAGVRBns5WAoIgB8oMQkpYFiLdzt0fkDZGEj4ZHsAbidZYUiE9WT0IrNzSKsbdMhqoODcqDjSuPMCzO8IFjA4ZWgAOVFZbH4oYugAcVFRABMAQXZ2OBA5KemoAG0YGmEacwBddr2Di0OzuN2j2GObvfvzGhgn3deH+I+v+-f2ttpvtDscaMEPpd7sFHucQVd4uDIWCQtc4ZcYYiLMjUQjhDcgc83iiIXD-uDYbcXsSQh9qbiAVSKd9TmTmV9GYTPqDvqTbn9mYy9hyeXzhTTMfi4V9JW9foK0TEubKEULdirLqzbpiBbAPjqaVLtYbKXtMZrFVyoSSkejRSScdD2TjdZi+YS4EgQLsTj1+AIstAAEoQcjIRYQdgAHhQNAAqgA+SIoKA6dSLFhQSxIADWSFEAHckFBGHs42c01IM3sUGdS0gIAA3SNQIgpogN5vsTJmeZLVbrEAx1O6KuZz3ek7xmjLEfp8den2RH1JjDbFOVpDV3bIABmLYAYjQAHSnvctoN1qB9lZrDZRoM0ENhreRqNxmgHhM0Xan4-LT8TiTAhtl2cs5zHPZO0jK9ZyIWdN23P9z3YKAAEkaBQqAABkr1-U8MKgD8cLOIgwJPU84x9X0eyCG8AFFtHoMAABsHBvAd73hF4pxCBN+AAegEmZrwWRZGOYtjlzyVB0EONQknsY40lkyAzkDCw4HEpjSFY9ixM4od4S+U5wX4oSRPMLSJN0qSsH2aI5NSBpVIgeTEmkJz6g8ex1MyVQkDYKAuAMu9NiwYdEMzUJwnQFcAAo4DWEDgT-DdRy3TMOLCmNwTCCB7CTUt21E-sctjEJ8sKk5+AASjkJMkvYP0AqC0Qc0iEKysHeLdm2BRnBIF9iD4Kh+pmJRhq8egICUGLoD6EbeDG6YBsIEgAoqTRJF0IgACJ5q0XQ9tG8bFBINwXM0PolGWRZFiWlbHHO4hLo8a6ZrmywXFIBBgCW-gTlqooLPajZ-PEIKXC0zrQp6vrVomoaKEes7BrIFHpp8EhDsW07pgstbZo2hSNBoHbgH2w6KZO5a0fW16VI+7HiDuh78ee9G3vEZnieIYJvt+-6+CgCzI3YUR2AAQm2ISAD8FblqAowAWhVqAImIPbuaQPaRoQTN82AKA4BYFgEC4OgXCk2wRK1zakj149AdqiHAuNuAWJYUQrMWWHuo2XqgZB4TxclmWLKgNXo5j2O46TBXBOEyrLHYYYoAAC1NqAAAZUzYhgJHilh6suvAkq4CBjfYCAAEdLAQGvMwARmd-hd2zZRgAQcQoALNQAGl8wLSKMureb7ASpq23qyZpla43tEiJrj13cN4vi7RaqIJeDecnyggwJNtGPMwMHPqBtZUvbauPPoQ9TNZw9l5Po6TKBFc-r-v5-3+---uWL8oAAHkXAACsIBdygHvMAogzYIGtpsYg2YIxrwbA9Z2vAgA)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a solution for you, but you can type your array like this:

```
type TypeArray = [mainType, contentType, buttonType, ...(mainType | contentType | buttonType)[]]
```

But this required that the first three elements of the array are in the right order.

Comment: Yes, that would work unfortunately in my use case I don't know order of the elements.